# How to enable/disable Pysimplegui button-1 click event

Tags: python, pysimplegui

With pysimplegui I am using a graph/canvas as a button and would like to enable/disable a button-1 click event based on a checkbox -could someone please offer a solution?  Thanks

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def handle_graph_click(event, your_variable):
    print(your_variable)


GSIZE = (80, 50)
graph = sg.Graph(GSIZE, (0, 0), GSIZE, key='-GRAPH-', background_color='#ffffff')
layout = [[sg.Checkbox("Checkbox", key='s1')],[graph]]
window = sg.Window("Graph Button", layout, use_default_focus=False, finalize=True, modal=True,no_titlebar=True)

canvas = graph.Widget
var = "12345"
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=500)
    if values['s1'] == True:
        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: handle_graph_click(event, var))
    else:
----> how to disable event here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by call `canvas.unbind("<Button-1>")`, of course, you can do it by set a flag to go or not in your binding callback.

Demo Code for PySimpleGUI code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

GSIZE = (80, 50)
graph = sg.Graph(GSIZE, (0, 0), GSIZE, key='-GRAPH-', background_color='#ffffff')
layout = [
    [sg.Checkbox("Checkbox", enable_events=True, key='s1')],
    [graph],
]
window = sg.Window("Graph Button", layout, finalize=True)
graph.bind("<Button-1>", "")
binding = False

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 's1':
        binding = values[event]
    elif event == "-GRAPH-" and binding:
        print("Click on Graph !!!")

window.close()
```